# pandas dataframe with read_csv cannot handle some column headers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

//Solved, with the comments from EdChum below I got the file to load, though still not 100% sure  what the problem was//

I'm new to using pandas etc, and I have a problem reading a tab delimeted 'csv' file. The roblem is as follows;

Rows in my csv look like this; First row is column names. (The escaping of the " and ' column names was added to this post to prevent the forum treating them as string delimeters, and # was escaped to prevent it being seen as a comment delimeter)

```
Reported    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z   \"  a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y   z   !   $   %   &   *   (   )   _   +   -   =   {   }   [   ]   :   @   ~   ;   \'  \#  <   >   ?   ,   .   /   Class
c-3785762359-20140807-06    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
spoaxclor1-bkp_Sun020820H00Mbpmp_cumu0_df_BPMP_21888_1.bus  1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   3   1   0   2   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   3   2   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   2   1   2   4   0   1   2   0   4   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   6   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1
BCC412_h7rcmumj_1_1 1   1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
spolxpdb4-bkp_Wed110503H00Mhrprd_af_HRPRD_25407_1.bus   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   2   1   0   1   0   3   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   3   0   3   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   4   0   2   2   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1
```

When I read this in using

```
df=pd.read_csv(outname,sep="\t",names=["Reported"]+char_list+["Class"])
```

where char_list is a list of all the single chars used as headers.

while loading I get the warning;

sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.

I am not sure if that warning has a bearing on my problem. The problem is that pandas does not appear to handle the values that are within the columns that have column names like '$' or '(' etc..,  as seen with

```
print df.std()
[8 rows x 81 columns]
A        0.964273
B        0.954714
C        0.799320
D        0.681608
E        0.761770
F        0.592568
G        0.378890
H        0.443973
I        0.545314
J        0.344022
K        0.499129
L        0.721499
M        0.497127
N        0.561301
O        0.980225
P        1.367463
Q        0.620526
R        0.821490
S        1.090850
T        0.688917
U        0.830025
V        0.441163
W        0.110650
X        0.392460
Y        0.197976
Z        0.215753
"        0.007530
a        0.085073
b        0.081841
c        0.037995
           ...   
y        0.542253
z        0.524417
!        0.271538
$             NaN
%             NaN
&             NaN
*             NaN
(             NaN
)             NaN
_             NaN
+             NaN
-             NaN
=             NaN
{             NaN
}             NaN
[             NaN
]             NaN
:             NaN
@             NaN
~             NaN
;             NaN
'             NaN
#             NaN
<             NaN
>             NaN
?             NaN
,             NaN
.             NaN
/             NaN
Class         NaN
dtype: float64
```

Values existing within columns headed by alpha characters are fine (along with a couple of non alpha characters),  but the majority of columns with non-alpha character headers don't appear to be handled properly and calculations return NaN

Is this  a limitation with pandas, or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: Won't this just load without specifying the column names?

Comment: If i remove the names= parameter read_csv interprets it has having 108 columns and gets it very wrong!  Actually, you gave me a clue; along with noticing the 'Class' colum is also failing to 'work' properly.  The NaN's appear after $ is used as a column header, I wonder if that is causing the problem. I'll check the read_csv docs and see if it has a special meaning..

Comment: You could just load the csv without the headers and then overwrite them after loading the csv e.g. `df=pd.read_csv(outname,sep="\t", header=None, skiprows=1)` then just assign direct to the columns attribute using your list `df.columns = ["Reported"]+char_list+["Class"]`

Comment: I'll try that :) - I tried removing $ but the NaN's then appear after z, so ! onward appear to fail, while ! worked previously. I wonder if there's a limit to number of columns or similar? - but yes, I'll try your suggestion and see how that goes too.

Comment: That worked! Kinda.. if I used the file as-is and used skiprows=1 I got the following; -- 

    #  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 538, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas/parser.c:5896)
    # pandas.io.common.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
 -- 
I tried removing the header line from the file altogether, then it loaded fine and no more columns report NaN on a df.std().

Thankyou :)